# How to get notified about logon/logoff and display lock/unlock on X11/X.org?

Tags: x11, xorg

Windows has [SENS](https://learn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/windows/desktop/api/_sens/) API which applications can use to get notified about logon/logoff and display lock/unlock events. Is there anything similar for X11/X.org or generally available interfaces and APIs in Linux desktops? I basically want something that would allow me to react to that within the user session.

Comment: try PAM https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/162783/how-can-i-detect-a-user-login-programmatically

Comment: When your connection to the X11 server breaks, the user logged out. Does that count?

Comment: A little more serious: logind emits DBus signals when sessions go and disappear, but since you are explicitly asking for X11 / X.org, this does not count as an answer either.

Comment: @UliSchlachter I have modified the question to be broader.

Comment: Just curious, why would you need this?

Comment: @n.m.: There is some sort of bug in either X.org or XFCE or elsewhere, where it resets monitor DPI settings if I log in after longer time when the session gets locked and monitors turned off. My workaround would be to run `xrander --dpi 144` on each unlock of the session.

Comment: Could it be that (for whatever reason) the monitor is deactivated and later activated again? With that I mean: It could "look like" the monitor was disconnected and thus gets reinitialised. You could use the RANDR X11 extension to write a small program that waits for RANDR notifications and then just re-applies DPI whenever such a notification comes in.

Answer (score 1):

Logind (which not all distros use) has an object on the system DBus. The signals of this object are available to any program and are documented as:

> The SessionNew(), SessionRemoved(), UserNew(), UserRemoved(), SeatNew(), SeatRemoved() signals are sent each time a session is created or removed, a user logs in or out, or a seat is added or removed.

https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/logind/

If logind is not in use, PAM might be your next best option, as sanjeev suggested. He links to https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/162783/how-can-i-detect-a-user-login-programmatically. However, note that this requires changing the system configuration and cannot be just subscribed to by any program.

Interacting with the screensaver is even less portable. For example, GNOME exposes a screensaver object on the user DBus instance. It is also possible to get events from the X11 server via the "SCREEN-SAVER" extension, but of course this is not available with Wayland.

https://people.gnome.org/~mccann/gnome-screensaver/docs/gnome-screensaver.html (Random Google result)

https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/doc/scrnsaverproto/saver.html#Events

Comment: While the logind approach seems like something useful, it seems to lack appropriate signals for the lock/unlock or seat activation. Or am I reading the [docs](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/logind/) wrong?

Comment: Yup, I don't see lock/unlock in there either, hence I suggested the screensaver extension for monitoring the screensaver. I'm not qute sure what you mean with seat activation.